# How to make my form site work on each device (responsive)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I developed a website and I use Boostrap 4 in my views to improve the user experience.

The site is mainly intended for use with a computer but I would like it to be usable from a tablet or a mobile.

For this I documented myself on the bootstrap site and I did several tests but I can not get the results I want.

Here's what, for example, a form looks like on my site (with a computer):

[image]

I would like that when the screen is smaller (tablet (like iPad) or mobile), the name of the field (for example Email) go alone in a line and take like class col-sm-12 and the field who is related to the name field go on the line of underneath and also take col-sm-12.
As the screen of a mobile is quite small I would also like to have a single field per line (and not 2 as is currently the case) in the case where the user uses a mobile or tablet.

From now on, i'm doing my tests with Chrome Debugger and the result work great on a Ipad Pro (big tablet) or higher.
I still need to fix it for mobile and tablet (who are smaller than Ipad Pro).

Currently this is what it look on a mobile with a Galaxy S5:

[image]

**Code**

```
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row col-12">
            <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-check-inline col-12">
                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                    </div>
                    <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div style="margin-left:33%">
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check-inline col-12" style="margin-top:1%">
                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                    </div>
                    <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div style="margin-left:33%">
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check-inline col-12" style="margin-top:1%">
                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword"></label>
                    </div>
                    <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see, it is far from perfect.

Also, it does not take the whole body size of the card so it is smallest than it should, is it a way to take the whole space only on a mobile?

Could you help me on how to get the desired result?

Comment: After each label, you could add a <br> tag.

Comment: @w1ll It does not change anything. But even if it was I only need a carriage return for col-sm and col-md.

Comment: Perheps you should add all the code you have, imcluding the card header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, something to begin with, most of the time it's best to develop (design) for mobile first, since most users are using a mobile nowadays. It makes it so much easier to scale to desktop from mobile since you are having more and more space along the way. That being said, there is a lot to improve on your current markup.

For example, a element should never have both a `row` class as `column` class (col-12). Imo the best way to structure a field with bootstrap classes is to have a `row` for each input field and label. Then, have a `col` class for every element, like one for the label and one for the input. After that, you have to decide which `cols` you would like to use.

Most of the time, you would like to start with the mobile view. The input and label should probably in your case take up 12 columns (because you want to have that full width). You should use a `col-12` class in this case. Because you maybe want the input and the label to be half size on tablets and desktop you also add the `col-md-6` class. That will span the input and label for 6 columns, so, 2 times 6 is 12 so they will span next to each other. You can read more about those columns [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/#grid-options).

To illustrate, I created an example that looks like what you desire.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <input type="text" id="name" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <input type="text" id="phone" />
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <input type="text" id="lastname" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <label for="email">E-mail</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <input type="text" id="email" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```